# Gaussian Random Vectors and their Distributions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, gaussian-integral

Let $X_{1},...,X_{N}$ be nondegenerate independent Gaussian random vectors from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Assume that each $X_{j}$ has its associate Gaussian distribution $\mu_{C_{j}}$, where:
\begin{eqnarray}
d\mu_{C_{j}}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{n}\det C}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\langle x, C_{j}^{-1}x\rangle}d\lambda^{n}(x) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
 where $\lambda^{n}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and each $C_{j}$ is a positive-definite matrix. I know for a fact that if we define a random vector $\tilde{X} := X_{1}+\cdots + X_{N}$, then $\tilde{X}$ will be Gaussian with distribution $\mu_{C}$, where $C = C_{1}+\cdots + C_{N}$, but I don't know how to prove it. I tried using the definition of distribution and using Characteristic functions but I gor nowhere. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:** In the comments, there is some ideas on how to prove the result. Let me add one more ingredient. It is easily proved that, with the above notation, if $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $\mu_{C}$-integrable then:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int d\mu_{C}(x)f(x) = \int d\mu_{C_{1}}(x_{1})\int d\mu_{C_{2}}(x_{2}) \cdots \int d\mu_{C_{N}}(x_{N})f(x_{1}+\cdots+x_{N}) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
And (\ref{2}) seems to be an indicative of the result of the question. Any ideas on how to use (\ref{2}) to prove it?

Comment: You are assuming the vectors $X_i$ are independent of each other?

Comment: Sure! Let me edit it!

Comment: This may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9879/addition-of-multivariate-gaussians

Comment: The first sentence in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem tells you how to put the pieces together.